# How to solve Gitbook don't work?

Tags: gitbook

When i use gitbook,the Table of Contents are as blows:
[image]

How to resolve it? There  is a remind:Need valid "ref" options

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you don't have a `SUMMARY.md`. At least I don't see one in your files Tree.

If it still doesn't work, do you have a link to your files?